# Looking for math audio resources online

Tags: online-resources

It is pretty difficult to find ***advanced math*** lectures online, though, with some effort, one can find a few (by "advanced" I mean ***anything beyond 1st or 2nd year of college, and preferably aimed at mathematicians, rather than engineers or scientists***).  The difficulty of this search becomes orders of magnitude greater if one is looking for audio-only lectures (that can be easily readily played in an mp3 player).  Of course, much of this has to do with the fact that it is difficult to communicate math without visuals, although it is definitely possible.

Does anyone know of any such resources (preferably free) online?

Thanks!

PS: one could, with considerable additional effort, extract the audio from, say, math video lectures on YouTube or iTunes, but I'm not too keen on this option, and not only because of the work involved.

Comment: I don t see why you had to down vote my answer, you only edited your question to exclude iTunes in addition to YouTube once I had provided it ...

Answer (score 4):

http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

Abstract Algebra from Benedict Gross at Harvard University.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a great resource containing tuns of stuff of the exact kind you are looking for ! Check out Itunes University, most major US schools and many of the top European ones have whole lectures series uploaded there, and they are available for free to download in many cases both audio and video.

Comment: Who down-voted this one? And why?

Comment: interesting question :) would be courteous if the kind benefactor had a least left a comment

Comment: @Beltrame: I don't know, but probably because you didn't give a link; etc.

Answer (score 3):

Advance mathematic courses are freely available at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#mathematics

Regards,
Arif

Answer (score 3):

There is several audio http://www.openculture.com/math_free_courses

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my original question in this excellent Math Overflow post:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2507/mathematical-podcasts-audio

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a book called Math Fundamentals for Audio which you can find here: https://www.areditions.com/gaston-bird-math-fundamentals-for-audio-das027.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.redhoop.org/search/?q=math. These are all online courses. Not sure how advanced they are though

Comment: Aren't these are video rather than audio?